# send notification alert from firebase sensor data

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database, push-notification

I am developing a mobile application using android studio.. My system is about reading data from sensor and sending the data to firebase database. The application is about displaying sensor data and graph as well generate a notification alert if the sensor data reach certain level.. Is there any possible way if I want to make it like that. I have search the internet but found no answer. Please help me solve this problem. Thank you

Comment: Im not sure whats the issue to be honest, you want to respond to a sensor when reached a certain level, whats holding you back? if you get sensor changes in your app can't you just do for example if (x>50 && y>60) { do somthing }?

Comment: I want to make the application to send a notification alert when the sensor data in firebase reach certain level.  I dont know how to do that . can you help me with this?

Comment: I still need more details, this sounds like if you focus your question youll find the answer.
What sensor? Its on the phone itself?
How do you want to respond it? on what terms?

Comment: Im using gas sensor. For sensor, I use Arduino IDE to send sensor data to firebase. To make the mobile application, I use the android studio to display the data. Now, I want to make a notification alert for the data. I want to make so that if the data  reach certain level, a notification alert will pop up in the mobile application. Is it  possible to do so?

Comment: Did you try listening to event change with snapshot?
https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen
you can set data on collection and listen to changes on it, thats what you mean?

Comment: You'll have to use Firebase Cloud Functions to send a FCM notification. You can look up here https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/use-cases

Comment: Here's a sample project to implement this 
https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/master/fcm-notifications